# Problems with filtering in ASP.NET core razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, razorengine

I'm new to c# ASP.NET razor pages and I'm using the sample in Microsoft traing to build an app. The code below works when I attempt to search an item like "Godzilla" from the movie table. The problem is that if Itry to search on "Godzilla", "GhostBusters" and "Kazzoky" it returns null.

so if searchString is "Godzilla", i get a result and same for "Kazzoky" and "Ghostbusters" biut when I pass "Godzilla,Kazzoky,Ghostbusters" as searchString, the result is a blank page.

Please help!!

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                 select m;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(SearchString));
    }

    Movie = await movies.ToListAsync();
}
```

I have tried

parts = parts.Where(s =>searchString.Contains(s.Title)); //didnt work

I have also tried 
movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(Where(s=>SearchString.Contains(s.Title))));

but it threw and exception...

Comment: Do you have data in the database?

Comment: Yes Erik. It's just the syntax to search multiple items using IQueryable that I can't find

Comment: Where does SearchString come from?

Comment: You are doing it wrong.It should be `SearchString.Contains(s.Title)`

Comment: Your question does not make sense, first you say `I try to search on "Godzilla" it returns null.` Then you go on to say `if searchString is "Godzilla", i get a result` so which is it?

Comment: This is my comment:   if searchString is "Godzilla", i get a result and same for "Kazzoky" and "Ghostbusters" but when I pass "Godzilla,Kazzoky,Ghostbusters" as searchString, the result is a blank page.    I hope you get it now...

Comment: [Cannot duplicate your problem with the code you've provided](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cRr7ph).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your inputs. I have solved the problem.

movies = movies.Where(s => SearchString.Contains(s.Title));

But I was testing it against a wrong dataset. For example a single search on "Gho" will return Ghostbusters but that is fine when you only want to search part of a title because you couldn't remember fully.

I was making this assumption and thats why i was having this problem.

Thanks everyone for your contributions, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one.

`movies = movies.Where(s => SearchString.Contains(s.Title));`

Comment: I've tried that already and it didn't work, I just omitted it so I don't cause much confusion. Thanks

Comment: I've also tried movies = movies.Where(s => s.Titke.Contains(Where(s=>SearchString.Contains(s.Title)))); but it threw and exception...

Comment: It should work with `SearchString.Contains(s.Title)` I have done it so many times. Debug your code and see if searchstring is correct. Also check if you have proper records in the db.

Comment: Its a little bit like trying to run a subquery against specific a field in a query....

Answer (score 0):

If your search is comma separated, you need to split it up:

```
var searchTerms = SearchString.Split(',');

movies = movies.Where(s => searchTerms.Contain(s.Title));
```